# How to deploy EAR applications on TIBCO BW 6.x?

Tags: tibco

I have tried deploying applications on BW 5.x using TIBCO Administrator 5.x and it works just fine. But with the newer versions, TIBCO Administrator does not works.
How should it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to Businessworks 6.x as "newer versions".
(Both are still further developed).
Businessworks 6 is administrated with the new Enterprise / TEA Administrator.
So to say a lot has changed between TEA Administrator and the TIBCO Administrator 5.x

Deployment for BW 6 could be done either:

- via Eclipse (TIBCO Studio) https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.0/doc/html/GUID-C4A95E9F-54BD-4CB0-8777-884845538BF7.html
- via Tea Agent commands: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.0/doc/html/GUID-EB8868D0-C764-48E7-B1D1-41CB8C319284.html

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy the BW 5.x application on TEA or vice versa. You can deploy BW 6x application on TEA and 5x applications on classic administrator.